# DRF (django-rest-framework) action decorator not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have this class view, that works perfectly for creating and listing objects of SiteGroup:

But I need a method to perform several operations on a single SiteGroup object, and objects associated with them. Therefore, I have tried to create a method, decorated with @action (as suggested by the docs).

According to the docs, this will autogenerate the intermediate url. Nevertheless, it doesn't work.

When I try to access (given that 423 is an existing SiteGroup Object):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/site-groups/423/replace_product_id/?product_id=0x345
```

the url is not found.

I also tried generating myself the URL in the urls.py, with no luck.

Can someone tell me where the problem is? I've browsed through all the docs, and found no clue. Thanks a lot.

```
class SiteGroupDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = SiteGroup.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser)
    serializer_class = SiteGroupSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'], url_path='replace_product_id', permission_classes=[IsSuperUser], url_name='replace_product_id')
    def replace_product_id(self, request, pk=None, device_type=None):
        serializer = SiteGroupSerializer(data=request.data)
        product_id = self.request.query_params.get('product_id', None)
        print("replace_product", product_id, device_type, pk, flush=True)
        return Response({"hello":product_id})
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from api import views, routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
enter code here
    url(r'^site-groups/', views.SiteGroupDetail.as_view()),

    url(r'^site-groups/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SiteGroupDetail.as_view()),

]
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing the router should be calling

```
super(OptionalSlashRouter, self).__init__()
```

What you have now calls `__init__` of SimpleRouter's parent, skipping the logic in `SimpleRouter.__init__`

Change that and see if it starts working

Actually as you're using python 3 it could be just

```
super ().__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks, I amented that, and, in the example I am calling SimpleRouter directly for clarity. 

Nevertheless, it is still not working.

Comment: does the action decorator rely on the view being registered with the router? I strongly suspect it does `router.register(site-groups', views.SiteGroupDetail)` - see the urls.py entry ends in `$`, so django can match `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/site-groups/423/`, but anything after the last `/` results in 404 because it does not match the regex

Comment: I see. You are right on that part. Nevertheless, I registered it like this:

`url('site-groups', views.SiteGroupDetail.as_view()),`

and also tried like:

`url(r'^site-groups/', views.SiteGroupDetail.as_view()),`

And, when accessing:

`http POST 127.0.0.1:8000/api/site-groups/423/replace_product_id/`


It just gets routed to /api/site-groups/423/ regular POST action (like if I was trying to create a new ressource).

Same happens if I change it to methods=['post', 'get'] and I try to access it by a get request.

Comment: Have you tried `router.register(site-groups', views.SiteGroupDetail)`?

Comment: When you tried did you also remove the two redundant `url(^site-groups`?

Comment: router.register('site-groups', views.SiteGroupDetail),

This yields this error type object 'SiteGroupDetail' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Comment: So, I registered:

`router.register('site-groups', views.SiteGroupDetail)`

But the thing is that, I have a view called SiteGroupList and another that is SiteGroupDetail. 

They are separated, as SiteGroupList serves the purpose of listing the SiteGroups and creating them in bulk, and the SiteGroupDetailView is the one responsible for single ressource creation and display (and where I want the new @action method).

Comment: `So, /site-groups/ is mapped to SiteGroupList
But site-groups/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/ was mapped to SitegroupDetail`

So, if register site-groups, and map it SiteGroupDetail, and I remove this line:

`url(r'^site-groups/', views.SiteGroupList.as_view()),` This view will never get called.

And, I did try removing it, just to try if site-groups/432/replace_product_id just work with your approcha, but because I am getting the "SiteGroupDetail" has no attribute 'get_extra_actions', I don't know if the approach is valid.

(thanks for helping, by the way :) )

Comment: ah that error is indicative of passing a `ListCreateAPIView` into the router. The router accepts viewsets only. This is good actually as a viewset will solve your other problem: you can put a method called `retrieve` for looking up a single object and a method called `list` for listing. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: Oh, that is perfect. Is there also a way, like there is for retrieving, for creating a single ressource and also several in bulk? (I realise now my former code can be very optimized. Your help is EXTREMELY appreciated).

Comment: Happy to help :) The documentation is clear: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions there is `create`, but no bulk create out of the box. Bulk create is not very restful FWIW, but there will be snippets on stackoverflow for adding the functionality

Comment: I had already solved bulk creation, with the other approach. I’ll have to mix them, I suposse. Thanks.